# Is this power supply not properly grounded?

Tags: power-supply, power, grounding, plug

**Quick Rundown**

The original power supply for my heat press machine (for t-shirts, hats, etc) machine went belly up, so I ordered a the only replacement that I could find that resembled the original.

**The Problem**
When I opened the new power supply up, I noticed that the grounding prong on the inside wasn't connected to anything. The original power supply did have a grounding wire that was connected to the chassis by a bolt. To my very-untrained eye, this seems like it would be the same as snipping the grounding prong off a power cable before plugging it in.

So is this thing actually that dangerous? Can I ground it myself?

[image: ground missing]

Comment: No, it isn’t and that’s illegal in most parts of the world.

Comment: @winny it's not dangerous? Or it's illegal to sell something like that?

Comment: check continuity from the earth pin to the chassis wall

Comment: Certainly dangerous. A better than nothing approach if you can’t return it to the seller would be to connect the chassis to the ground pin. Every loose metallic panel needs ground connection too, via cable or sharp lock washers which bite though the paint.

Comment: @tobalt I'll do that as soon as I can borrow a multimeter (i know, shameful)

Comment: @winny I'll see about returning it, it was an aliexpress order so who know's how that'll go. I was considering scavenging the grounding wire from the old power supply and using it here.

Comment: @tobalt I’m missing the English term for it. What are they called?

Comment: @tobalt yea the body of the plug itself is plastic, it can slide out of the chassis.

Comment: Mr Ali does not have your well-being on top of his mind. I avoid buying anything mains connected from there.

Comment: Slide? If you need less  than 2 N of force to move it, there’s another code violation for you.

Comment: @winny yea you're not kidding. It's more than a little horrifying that I could have just plugged this is and tried to use it.

Comment: @SuperStew then there is certainly no reliable connection. Even if you ground the chassis at one place via a wire and some kind of cutting washer: i wouldn't trust this piece of trash to extend the earth to all chassis parts. Unearthed, it will likely operate fine. but is dangerous if a wire gets lose..Only use in emergency

Comment: @winny yea the plug is held in place in the chassis by a couple of bolts, if I take those out, it slides right out.

Comment: Bolts are fine.

Comment: If this is the only replacement you can find, I'd look into whether the original can be repaired. But I expect other replacements should be available, they might just not look much like the original (particularly if the machine is old--you might be replacing a bulky, expensive linear supply with a tiny lightweight modern switching supply).

Comment: @tobalt thanks, it's concerning that's how the original was grounded. What would be the best way to ground something like this? (not that i'll try it myself, just curious)

Comment: @Hearth yea possibly, I'm trying to get a hold of original manufacturer, but having a certified electrician repair it would likely exceed the cost of replacing the whole thing.

Comment: Post a new question about repairing the old one. Take the Tour and FAQ first because there are some limitations on repair questions.

Comment: @SuperStew It's likely the only thing you'd need to do is replace a dead capacitor or something. So do a bit of research on it and post a new question here, and it'll probably be easy enough. But if you're not confident, we might also be able to help you find a suitable replacement, too.

Comment: Show all F/R sides and interior of PS and what were the specs you ordered?

Comment: @Hearth I actually did try to repair the old one, not sure if I should have, but I did. One of the wires going to the main on/off switch "blew" out of it's plastic housing. I could hold the wire back in place and get it to work, but the plastic that was holding it was melted/gone.

Comment: @SuperStew This is one of the problems of buying stuff from across the world from a random seller. They produce something as cheap as they can, with safety (and often, quality) an afterthought. Because _you_ are the one importing the product into your country, _you_ are responsible for ensuring the product conforms to safety regulations in your country. Sellers are not obligated to do this (and if they were, there's little recourse for them), and buyers don't bother, so people end up with unsafe crap. But hey, it was cheap ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately some manufacturers, particularly ones in China, seem to treat grounding as an optional extra.  If the importer (into your country) isn't going to test the grounding, then they don't bother fitting it.

Unless you are confident that the power supply is double insulated, then it's wrong, and should be fixed.  That should not be too hard to do.

Comment: How might one fix it?

Comment: The terminals on the 3-way connector look like they take standard push-on "spade" terminals, probably 1/4" or 6.3mm.  Acually, the terminal on the connector is the spade, and you need the part that pushes onto that.  Run a suitable ground wire from that terminal to a screw on the case.  Ideally, use a ring connector at the screw end.

Answer (score 0):

When a power transformer is used with low voltage high current, a ground wire may not be necessary.

The usual requirement for 2 pronged plugs or without the PE ground connection is "double insulation" for redundancy.

- otherwise, a link to supplier brand might be useful for further review of safety or more detailed photo's .
- where did you get this? It likely has no valid certs near the socket.

Comment: You’re not allowed to have a C13 inlet for a double insulated product. C13 + metal chassis = chassis must be grounded.

Comment: I didn't find a website for the manufacturer, but this is their current aliexpress listing. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2251832632599329.html

Comment: Also I got the replacement power supply just a few weeks ago